# How do I get the rendered output of a controller's action without visiting the web page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As part of the deployment process for our rails 2.3 app, I'd like to save static versions of our error pages to the public folder.  How do I get the rendered output of a controller's action without visiting the web page?  I know it can be done because the functional tests do it - if I say

```
get :errors, :id => 404
```

then the body is in @response.body.  I suppose I could just copy the code out of ActionController::TestCase, but I'm hoping that there's a simpler way to do it.

Comment: I wonder if page caching would work here so the page is generated on first hit, or are you concerned that a 404 means your app is pretty broken so you can't rely on the Rails stack?

Comment: Yeah - I want something to display if, say, all the mongrels are busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I did just go into ActionController::TestCase, and this is what I dug out:

```
def get_content host, path, filename
  request = ActionController::Request.new 'HTTP_HOST' => host,
                                          'REQUEST_URI' => path,
                                          'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
                                          'rack.input' => '',
                                          'rack.url_scheme' => 'http'

  controller = ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize(request).new
  response = ActionController::Response.new
  controller.process request, response
  return response.body
end
```