# capturing output of a controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to be able to capture the output of a controller action as a string - you'd think it would be a relatively easy thing but I can't get any of the render/render_to_string methods to work.

I need to be able to store a reference to a controller and action and then be able to grab it's output further on in a process (actually server side printing)

Any ideas - thanks?

Using render/render_to string like (in a model)

```
view = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths)
view.extend ApplicationHelper
output = view.render(:action => '<someaction>', :controller => '<somecontroller')
```

this results in;

```
/Users/---/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing': undefined method `formats' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

if i try to use render_to_string I get;

```
undefined method `render_to_string' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000010400c760> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: show the way you use `render_to_string`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the rendered output of a controller's action without visiting the web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106724/how-do-i-get-the-rendered-output-of-a-controllers-action-without-visiting-the-we)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use curl?

```
curl http://localhost:3000/controller/action
```

Using *curl* gem, you can call it even from console:

```
require 'curl'
page = CURL.new.get('http://localhost:3000/controller/action')
```

**UPDATE**

From the rails console:

```
app.get('/controller/action')
app.response.body
```

Comment: that is possibly an option - URL is protected though so would have to overcome that locally from local connections

Comment: OK, see my update. There are several ways to fetch page content directly from rails console, this is the simplest one.